# LNK2019 errors on project that has identical properties to another one that works

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw, lnk2001

Using Visual Studio Community 2017

I have 4 projects:

1. Static library project that uses GLFW and couple other libraries
2. ProjectA which uses that library, compiles fine
3. ProjectB which also uses that library, compiles fine
4. ProjectC which I recently created and uses the library, does not compile

ProjectC has the same properties as ProjectB and ProjectA, nothing should be different, right?

But somehow, I get these errors when compiling ProjectC:

> glfw3.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
>
> audio.lib(au.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__stricmp

I tried building GLFW and Audio library from their sources and replaced the project ones with newly built ones, no effect.

Comment: The missing functions are from the Microsoft C runtime library.  Check your linker setting for ProjectC.  Double check that you are building with the same shared/static runtime support setting on all projects.

Comment: I double checked everything, I checked differences on the .vcxproj files, everything is same (except project GUID)

Comment: Okay this is pretty weird, I made a new Solution, made a new Project and did all the setting stuff, getting the errors and all that. I copied ProjectB into the solution and added it, compiled it without any errors. Then I took the source and header files from ProjectC into ProjectB, included them in the ProjectB and excluded the other original ones, errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, I somehow managed to untick "Inherit from parent or project defaults" checkbox in Additional Include Directories.

Check your checkboxes everybody!